# how to get bootstrap popovers to work with dynamically generated image links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to get the Bootstrap 2 "popovers" to:

A) work with dynamically generated content and
B) display an image inside of the popover.

My current code:

```
var image = '<img src="img/header/'+selection+'" />';
var previewLink = '<a class="headerPreview" href="#" rel="popover" >(Hover to Preview)    </a>';
$('#headerBlock').append(previewLink);
$('.headerPreview').popover({
    title: 'test',
    content: image
});
```

Right now, it does nothing when the link is hovered over. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/KAvAZ/

The key is adding `trigger: 'hover'` to your popover object.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. I thought it defaulted to hover :\ thank you for the help. However, I have one more issue; this popover is inside of a modal window, and the popover currently is appearing behind the modal - anyway to fix that?

Comment: Yes. Add a CSS rule to make the `z-index` property of the popover high enough to place it in front of the modal. `.headerPreview { z-index: 99; }`

Comment: thank you, but it still appears to be behind the modal window even with the CSS z-index setting.

Comment: try bumping it up to 99999 or something :)

Comment: No go, even with 9999 :( I console.logged the z-index of the modal, and it's only 1050. No idea why the popover wont work. note I also have the black modal background shadow enabled, wonder if that's the issue..

Comment: Now I'm an idiot. You want to set the z-index of the `.popover` class, not `.headerPreview`. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Each time you dynamically add some new content, if you want to make it popover-enabled (assume that your already add proper html tags), popover() function should be called right after you add the new content. This is what I do to enable popover on both original content and dynamically generated content.

This thread may help: [Twitter Bootstrap Popovers not working for Dynamically Generated Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947094/twitter-bootstrap-popovers-not-working-for-dynamically-generated-content)