# Remove class when another class in seperate div is added

Tags: jquery, class, find

How can I remove the class ".visible" in header when the class ".active" in section is added?
".active" is dynamically added trough scrolling via a plugin.

```
<header class="visible">
    <div id="menu-bar">
    </div>
</header>

<section class="part-one active" data-panel="start">
</section>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect class changing by DOMAttrModified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172470/how-to-detect-class-changing-by-domattrmodified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setInterval()` to continously check to see if the class has been added.

```
function checkForClass(){
    if ($("section").hasClass("active")) {
        $("header").removeClass("visible")
    }
   setInterval('checkForClass()',1000)//every 1 second...
}
```

Or alternatively, amend the plugin to remove the class on successfully adding the `.active` class

Comment: You following me around ;-)