# Add class if two id has same value

Tags: javascript, html

I have the two divs, One for questions another one for answers. if the div id `ques0` has `here` class `<div id="ques0" class="showquestion here"></div>`, respect to answers id `qstats0` of parent `tr` added class of `highlight`.

**HTML**

```
<!--Question-->
    <div id="ques0" class="showquestion here"></div>
    <div id="ques1" class="hidequestion"></div>
    <div id="ques2" class="hidequestion">

<!--Answer-->
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">1</td>
    <td valign="top" id="qstatschoice0">A</td>
    <td id="qstats0">N</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">2</td>
    <td valign="top" id="qstatschoice1">A</td>
    <td id="qstats1">N</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">3</td>
    <td valign="top" id="qstatschoice2">A</td>
    <td id="qstats2">N</td>
    </tr>
```

I want output like below.

```
<!--answer-->
    <tr class="highlight">
    <td valign="top">1</td>
    <td valign="top" id="qstatschoice0">A</td>
    <td id="qstats0">N</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Hint: what your mainqus and popqus variables contain are strings - not the ids. (And they will never equal each other, because one starts with "ques", the other with "qstat")

Comment: that's not jquery :)

Comment: I'm guessing he means the number at the end of the id. You have to parse that.

Comment: The question value may have more values. I have to check the condition. if the particular question have '.here' class, I should find the same ques value from answers and highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

The ids are not the same(and it should not be), but there is a relationship ie the numeric part of the ids are the same so you can use `replace()` to find out the `td` with id `qstats<x>`(where `x` is the numeric part of the id of the `here` element) then find the `tr` ancestor of it and highlight it.

```
function highlight() {
    var $c = $('.showquestion'),
        //get the id of here element
        id = $c.attr('id');
    //find the tr to highlight
    $('#' + id.replace('ques', 'qstats')).closest('tr').addClass('highlight')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c7zz047m/)

Comment: thanks. Its worked in demo. but in live I have missed something.

Comment: how can i remove '.highlight' automatically if '.here' chnaged to another div.

Comment: @Azzah that you have to do manually.. ie call the highlight method again when the class is changed..

Comment: @Azzah another option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172470/how-to-detect-class-changing-by-domattrmodified

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you use jQuery..

```
document.getElementById('current_question')
$("#current_question") // jquery way ;-)
```

try smthg

```
$("#an_id").addClass("blabla");
$("#an_id").removeClass("blabla");
```

btw, if many div's have the same ID, i think only the last one in the DOM will match.

Comment: The question value have more values. I have to check the condition. if the question have '.here' class i should find the same ques value and highlight

Answer (score 0):

First: document.getElementById is clean javascript, not jquery.
Second: try something like this:

```
var question = $('#ques0').text();
var answer = $('#qstats0').text();
if (question == answer) {
    answer.parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
}
```

Some info: ids have no value. It's just identificator of an element. .text() gets all text inside selected element.

---

Tell me if I understood something wrong and if so - please provide more information.

Best regards.

Comment: @Papsoft. The question value have more values. I have to check the condition. if the question have '.here' class i should find the same ques value and highlight.