# Know if a class was added (was added with javascript)

Tags: javascript, css

I am programming a web and i need to know when a Class was added. 
I am using a JavaScript plugin and the plugin add a CSS Class in then deletes it and add it in other div (gallery). I need to know in every moment in which 'div' is this class.

Here you have an example of what I want to do

```js
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
});

if ($('div').hasClass("red")) {
  $("div").addClass('border');
}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}
.border {
  border: 6px #000 solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
```

As you see in this example, I want to add the class `border` only when the class `red` was added, can not do it together with the class `red` because as i say in the real page I am using a JavaScript plugin.

Comment: *"I need to know in every moment in wich 'div' is this class."* I bet you don't, but you think you do because of something *else* you need to do. What do you really need to do?

Comment: Why not just add border: 6px #000 solid, to your .red class css?..  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi :) thanks for the comments. This is only an example because the page is more complicated to explane hier. As explained above. Using a (slider) plugin. This plugin add a class in the active div (the slide currently displayed) i need add other class in this moment (i want to add a .load()). But javascript is executed only one time and then don´t know when other div have after the class

Comment: @TamZam: There is no event raised by a class change. But you can get a notification of it, through a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) thanks four your Ideas.

As @T.J. Crowder writed Mutation Observer is a very good option for this question.

Hier a link with the Answer:
[How to detect class changing by DOMAttrModified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172470/how-to-detect-class-changing-by-domattrmodified)