# How to use jQuery to check if an element is added to page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using [endless scrolling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised), and when I have scrolled x amount of pixels there will be added new objects to the page. But how can I use jQuery to check if a new element (`class` or `id`) is added to the page?

(I want to check this, because if a new element is added I want to do some jQuery on the new element).

Comment: Do you mean a new element added dynamically on to the page?

Comment: Did my answer not help you?

Comment: @allegutta In that case do you have control over when the element is added on to the page. Also have a look at mutation observer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @KyleK seems like OP is looking for a way to detect a new element added on to the page dynamially

Comment: Isn't your own code responsible for dynamically adding elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use .length, to check if it exists, after an append()

```
$('#elemId').length;
```

Like so...

```
if($('#elemId').length > 0){ //your code here };
```

Or write your own function....

```
jQuery.fn.Exists = function(){
    return jQuery(this).length > 0;
};
```

Then use it to return true or false...

```
if($('#elemId').Exists()){ //your code here };
```

Or you can use the livequery() plugin...

```
$('#elemID').livequery(function()
{
// do things here like binding new events and stuff.
// this function is called when an object is added.
// check the API for the deletion function and so on.
});
```

I can't seem to find the plugin anymore, on the jQuery website, but it did exist at one point

You can also try DOMNodeInserted...

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
console.log(e.target, ' was inserted');
});
```

You can use on()....if your selector will always be the same...

So for instance, say as you scroll you're always adding a new div called class="newDiv"....

Then the jquery you want to perform....if you want to bind an event to click...

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.newDiv', function(){ //your code here
 });
```

Comment: hmmm i have heard about livequery. Probably take a look at mutation observer the link i posted in the orignal comment and this one i answered a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990573/how-to-bind-bootstrap-popover-on-dynamic-elements/16991216#16991216

Comment: DOMNodeINserted is mutation event and it is deprecated.

Comment: `on()` is probably your best bet in this case. It works by taking advantage of event bubbling.

Comment: @MattBrowne `on()` is for binding the events, but he want to apply something on the element created dynamically. proabably like applying a plugin or something...

Comment: @KyleK Yes, if he just wants to bind events, but if you want to apply a plugin on dynamic created elements, then this isnot possible. `.on()` is for binding the events. he says he wants to do some jquery to the new elements not sure what he means whether apply some plugins.. ?

Comment: Yes true, but I assume he just wants to perform standard jQuery, like click handling, mouseover/mouseout events etc

Comment: Sorry for not accept this answer for correct before! Thanks :)