# Adding different Twitter Bootstrap popovers to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to add popovers to dynamically created elements. Each kind of element (either a ContentEditable or an Img or a Video) needs to have a different popover content.

Because they are dynamic elements, I'm calling the popovers as follows:

```
$('body').popover({
            selector: '[rel=popoverImage]',
            content: **popoverImage**,
            html: true,
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'focus'
        });
```

Where `popoverImage` is a variable that has the content of the popover for the img element.

The issue comes when I try to add another popover. It doesn't show. I've tried the following:

1. Having 2 Selectors and calling them in different `$('body')popover({...})` functions.
2. Changing the `body` element to a dynamically generated container.
3. Changing the variable that has the "content" data each time a new element is focused.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is when you add a new control add the popover at the same time:

```
function AddNewElement()
{
  var yourElement = '<div id="yourElementId"> The element you want </div>';
  $('divToAppend').append(youElement);

  var yourPopoverContent = 'Your Personalized popover';

  $('#yourElementId').popover({
      html : true,
      content : yourPopoverContent      
  });

}
```

This should work with your actual code for the popover.

Comment: Agreed works great but needs comma after html parameter $('#yourElementId').popover({
      html : true,
      content : yourPopoverContent      
  });