# Unable to Display Popover on Hover td element of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using below code also find the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/atotadhm/1qnpnwao/) .Could you please help on this.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="myrow1">                         
    <td class="cpCode">
     <span rel="replace">Need PopOver</span>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

```
jQuery(function($) {
      $('[rel=replace]').popover({trigger: 'hover',
              placement : 'top', 
              html: 'true',                            
              content :'Hello'                             
                  });                     
 });
```

Comment: can you please explain more about it?

Comment: i think you have provided the wrong fiddle

Comment: Hello Siddharth, Please check now updated the fiddle

Comment: man you can not see the popover because it is `top` aligned and it is getting hidden, change it to `bottom` and see the magic

Comment: It is because you didn't add JQuery in it. Check https://jsfiddle.net/1qnpnwao/1/. It's working

Comment: I am able to get in fiddle this is my fidddle link It works fine in fiddle but not in code. I have used popover in other pages it is working well.Below is how I am creating the td . 

    $(this).append('<td class="cpCode" onclick="removeSingle(event)"> <span rel="replace" data-toggle="popover">' + key + '</span></td>'); td and its text are displaying fine.but not popover

Answer (score 0):

I saw your fiddle, you missed bootstrap/jquery files, here is the same [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6bx4z2r/) and it is working fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[rel="replace"]').popover({
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement : 'bottom', 
          html: 'true',                            
          content :'Hello' 
    });   
});
```

Comment: Hello Siddharth, I am able to get in fiddle this is my fidddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/atotadhm/bvb3L851/)

It works fine in fiddle but not in code. I have used popover in other pages it is working well.Below is how I am creating the td .
    $(this).append('<td class="cpCode"           onclick="removeSingle(event)">    <span rel="replace" data-toggle="popover">' + key + '</span></td>');

td and its text are displaying fine.but not popover

Comment: Check this link to add popover for dynamic elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990573/how-to-bind-bootstrap-popover-on-dynamic-elements

Comment: I did a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr02bL5c/) for this, you need to use `selector` option of `popover` as @NarendraCM mentioned

Comment: Awsome Naendra CM and Siddharth. Working Now! Great.