# Javascript method wont work with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so if this was to do with a click event i would know to do something like ...

```
$('body').on('click','.element',function(){
     ....do something
});
```

But the code i have here is:

```
$('.checkout .popbtn').popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'bottom',
    animation: false,
    content: function(){
        return $('#popover').html();
    }
});
```

.popbtn is the dynamically generated element.

How can i get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Edit the code which defines `popover`.

Comment: your question is unclear, where is element `.element`

Comment: You need to call it when you add the elements.

Comment: Probably you can attach the event after you populate the element or the element is generated. Little more code or a sample fiddle will be helpful

Comment: This stackoverflow answer has a few options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990573/how-to-bind-bootstrap-popover-on-dynamic-elements

Answer (score 0):

When your button gets added to the page, call your `code`.

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMNodeInserted to get when the element is created on the page

`$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.popbtn', function () {
     $('.checkout .popbtn').popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'bottom',
    animation: false,
    content: function(){
        return $('#popover').html();
    }
});
});`