# multiple bootstrap popovers with unique ids- not working on shown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create and initialize multiple popovers, using the same code. The html element is being created in JS-

`var panel = ('<a href="javascript://" id= "'+popId+'" data-title="xyz" >');`

`popId` is a unique value for each so the ids getting assigned are unique

Next I am calling the following function-

```
createPopOver("#"+popId,<another_arg>);
```

The create function looks like this-

```
function createPopOver(selector,<another_arg>) {
  $(selector).popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    placement : 'left'
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    console.log("reached here1"+selector);
    ...
  });
}
```

debugging through the control goes to the function however not inside the shown event and so the console does not print anything.

If I give an `id="xyz"` so now all the popovers have the same id, the very first popover will show up on clicking but with incorrect text (the content to display is being computed in the create popover function).

Comment: I see that you are trying to create dynamic `popovers`. When you are attaching `panel` to `DOM`? Could you please post complete `js` relating to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when you create your popovers and when you initialize them.

```
function createPopOver(selector,another_arg) {
   console.log(selector);
  //$(selector).popover();
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({

  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    console.log("reached here1"+selector);
  });  
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    var panel = $('<p><a href="javascript://" id= "123" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here\'s some amazing content. It\'s very engaging. Right?" >123</a></p>');
     $('body').append(panel);
     panel = $('<p><a href="javascript://" id= "234" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title 234" data-content="And here\'s some amazing content. It\'s very engaging. Right? 234" >234</a></p>');
     $('body').append(panel);
     panel = $('<p><a href="javascript://" id= "345" data-title="xyz" >345</a></p>');
     $('body').append(panel);
     panel = $('<p><a href="javascript://" id= "456" data-title="xyz" >456</a></p>');
     $('body').append(panel);      
    createPopOver("#123",'');
    createPopOver("#234",'');
    createPopOver("#456",'');

 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v761q32b/

Comment: Thank you so much! I was initializing before attaching it to the DOM which was the real issue. Your snippet really got me into thinking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have a strong feeling that you are initializing `popover` by calling `createPopOver` function, before you attach elements to `DOM`, which ain't gonna work. Because event's can be attached to the `elements` only when it gets attached to the `DOM`. Alongside, `id` isn't necessary to attach `popover`. You can make use of `class` which can be given to multiple elements, or you can make use of `rel` or `data-*` attributes.

```
var panel = ('<a href="javascript://" id= "'+popId+'" rel="popover" data-title="xyz" >');
```

Now you can write `createPopOver` function without the `selector` argument and `popover` has `selector` option where you can specify the **selector** and attach the `popover` to `body`.

```
function createPopOver(<another_arg>) {
  $('body').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    placement : 'left',
    container: 'body',
    selector: '[rel="popover"]', //considering rel as common attribute here
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    console.log("reached here1"+$(this).attr('id'));
    ...
  });
}
```

You can call `createPopOver` once your contents of `panel` variable gets attached to the `DOM`.

There are various other ways to work on with. Do refer **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16991216/2065039)** for a detailed explanation on other options.

Comment: Thank you so much! yes you are right I was trying to initialize the popover before attaching it to DOM and that was causing the issue.

Comment: @newjersey2017 Anytime.. Happy Coding.. Do accept the answer if it helped.. :)