# Show and hide a popover on click of div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, popover

Here is my jsfiddle: [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/4x0nnkap/)

After drag n drop of "rule/event" class into "layout" class, how to create a popover with HTML form on-click or double-click of the dropped components?

```
$('[rel="popover"]').popover({
    alert("hi");
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
            return clone;
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990573/how-to-bind-bootstrap-popover-on-dynamic-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind bootstrap popover on dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990573/how-to-bind-bootstrap-popover-on-dynamic-elements)