# not all Bootstrap popovers displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two popovers on my page, which points to elements identified by their IDs:

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
        var popOverSettings = {
            placement: 'right',
            selector: '#diag1',
            trigger: "hover"
        };
        $(this).popover(popOverSettings);
    });

    $('document').ready(function() {
        var popOverSettings = {
            placement: 'right',
            selector: '#diag2',
            trigger: "hover"
        };
        $(this).popover(popOverSettings);
    });
```

Though only one is showing ? Any idea how to tweak the Js to allow multiple popovers (there me bay a few more, with an Id assigned dynamically)

Comment: so only the second one is showing right ?

Comment: `there me bay a few more, with an Id assigned dynamically` if so then **use class selector instead of Id's**

Comment: yeah but popover content is different in each ID, and is defined in the very IDentified element (a div)

Comment: second one showing indeed

Comment: add a class to all the elements for which you want the popover and then use this class in the `selector` property.

Comment: Damn, thank you ! works

Comment: Glad you got it working :) .. happy coding

Comment: @Maxence if your problem has been solved then you can delete this question.

Comment: @RohanKumar why delete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990573/how-to-bind-bootstrap-popover-on-dynamic-elements

Comment: so do i delete ?

Comment: No it's not a duplicate of the mentioned thread

Comment: Ok. and I will learn Js and Jquery. I am struggling so much with all these tiny Js bits: popover, toggle, ... and cannot make them work properly. so frustrating.. tks