# Use BootStrap PopOver in Joomla-Backend

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I would like to use the Bootstrap PopOver (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers) in the backend of my component.

Well, the Tooltips already work by using:

```
echo JHTML::_('tooltip','test','','','Test');
```

But the popovers do not work this way. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Did you check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947094/twitter-bootstrap-popovers-not-working-for-dynamically-generated-content?rq=1 ?

Comment: Have you checked the [Joomla API](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlBootstrap.html#method_popover) for popovers? @Ramy, Joomla supports Bootstrap popovers using the API, no need to manually do it with JS ;)

Comment: I'm using Joomla 3.3.3

I read http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlBootstrap.html#method_popover, but I do not know how to apply that on my component.

Maybe you can give me a hint how to use this with JHtml?

I thought it would be like the way I described above, but I'm getting the error "JHtml::popover not found".

Comment: Can you please provide the code you actually using for the popover in your question?

Comment: Hi Lodder,


i tried it this way:

`// Get BootStrap Framework
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');`

and

`echo JHTML::_('popover','test','','','Test');`


But this does not work.

`echo JHTML::_('tooltip','test','','','Test');`

works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to initiate the popover js file like so:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.popover');
```

You can then use the following HTML markup which calls the popup:

```
<small class="hasPopover" data-placement="top" title="Header" data-content="Content">Hover over me</small>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great - thank you. 

That helps a lot. I thought it would be possible to echo it via JHTML like in my tooltip-example.

Is there any possibility to show the popover on mouse click?